# index for jObject properties not working c#

Tags: c#, json, bitcoin

I am parsing a Bitcoin transaction `String` into a `JObject` (it is in JSON format) and want to reference the `prev_out` hash and second value in the JSON String (see below for an example). As you can see below I have tried to get the property values using the index but I keep getting `null` back. Please help!

What the Typical JSON string looks like:

```
{
    "hash" : "4ebf7f7ca0a5dafd10b9bd74d8cb93a6eb0831bcb637fec8e8aabf842f1c2688",
    "ver" : 1,
    "vin_sz" : 1,
    "vout_sz" : 2,
    "lock_time" : 0,
    "size" : 225,
    "in" : [{
            "prev_out" : {
                "hash" : "bf7d91ac70917f98b497927e1b07267507652b206df14ecdba2e9390b9bffc65",
                "n" : 0
            },
            "scriptSig" :
            "                               3044022069b6b0f1a8d453bdb89e3ad475232b8e01d2851e7b53acab3f830f40e80b3b5102203c0   49
                    867975360020293c735d48b4a2dda003aa781c1d8ccd2c7af290dcd11de01
                    02e3538427350039e67ea99e935cefb740badf3d09ebc301b0bc9d1bb0301a3417"
        }
    ],
    "out" : [{
            "value" : "0.08990000",
            "scriptPubKey" : "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 5b1d720daf0e95e37d0eaedd282b6ed9a40bab71
                     OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG"
        }, {
            "value" : "0.01000000",
            "scriptPubKey" : "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 71049fd47ba2107db70d53b127cae4ff0a37b4ab
                    OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to reference the `prev_out` hash value using this:

```
JObject transaction = JObject.Parse(t1);
var d = transaction["in"][0]["hash"];
```

Where `t1` is the JSON transaction string

I try to get the second `value` property using this:

```
JObject v = JObject.Parse(t1);
var val = v["out"][1]; //second value starting from 0
value = val.ToString();
```

Comment: what is your exact question ?
How a JSON string looks like?

Comment: Please format the JSON properly, it is unreadable.. Also try to make it the string that is in `t1` at the time of parsing.

Comment: I have just tried to validate and format your JSON with an online validator tool, and it gives an error that JSON is malformed (tried multiple tools).  Please double check that your JSON is valid and, as others have suggested, format properly so that it can be analyzed easier by us folks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"hash" lives inside "prev_out", so you need to access it like this:

```
var d = transaction["in"][0]["prev_out"]["hash"];
```

This becomes clear if you format the JSON.